# Is there a way to password protect a .pem file so it prompts you to enter a password before adding the extention to Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pem

I have created a basic Chrome extension and it generated a key.pem file.

Is there anyway to password protect the key.pem file so I get prompted each time I want to install this extenions on Google Chrome?

I've tried using the following; where I enter a password used to protect the file, but when I try to package this extension it says "invalid private key"

openssl genrsa -des3 -out key.pem 2048

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this thread help?

http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/bKoAAPX4iVA/aXZ_Cy0TJ3kJ

I'm not sure if this still works with the latest Chrome, but it was posted October 2012 so it probably does.

Hope this helps :)

*Edit: sorry if this is completely not what you were hoping for :)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's not what I'm looking for but it's good to know you. Thanks